# cardano-db-sync table link diagram?

Tags: cardano-db-sync

Is a diagram showing cardano-db-sync table links available?

i'm aware of the schema.md file, was after something more visual.

Answer (score 3):

There is an Entity Relationship Diagram (ERD) [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/blob/master/doc/ERD.png)